# What is the purpose of the "Rev" field when editing a question?

Tags: support, edits

At some point since I last edited a question on Stack Overflow, a "Rev" field (drop-down) was added to the edit page, with no explanation of its purpose.

The list contains the description and name associated with each revision so far, but why?

Answer (score 24):

Actually, that's been there for a while. It's so you can edit a post from a previous revision of the post.

If you select a previous revision from the dropdown, the text in the editor will change to display the markdown from that previous revision. This was fixed recently, as the functionality didn't work for a while. From there, you can either submit the edit as-is, or you can edit further from that previous revision and fix other mistakes seen there.

[image: What it looks like when picking a previous revision from the dropdown]

If you look to the upper right of the image, you'll see you also get a warning that saving this edit will effectively rollback the post you're editing.

This is mildly useful for users with less than 2k rep who see an edit that vandalizes a post, want to fix it, and potentially want to clean up the previous revision a bit as well. *However* it's not that common to need this ability, and you need to explain what you're doing in the edit summary *very well* to have a better chance of the edit being approved.

This is really more useful for 2k rep users who need to rollback a post, yet fix up the previous revision. Their edits don't have to go through review and are applied automatically. Except in very clear-cut cases, probably best to leave this ability to them.

Comment: Sidenote: One can also select a specific version to edit from the revision history of a post